# Scaling images in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, image, filter

My page contains an image like in example below. Width of the image depends on browsers width and height is being changed authomaticly (something like ).

This image looks nice after resizing in all browsers except IE (I've tested in IE7 and IE6). In IE image looks ugly. Some parts are thicker than should be and some parts are thinner.

[alt text http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/7202/88017917.png](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/7202/88017917.png)

I'm almost sure that it is due to IE doesn't use smoothing. But I wonder how to solve this  unpleasent problem?

---

I dont have ie7 but this code should work fine there. But how to fix it for ie6?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    img { -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 50%;">
    <img src="pp.jpg" width="100%">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[From flickr devs:](http://code.flickr.com/blog/2008/11/12/on-ui-quality-the-little-things-client-side-image-resizing/)

> IE 6 is a riskier proposition, but can
>   show improved image resizing when the
>   AlphaImageLoader CSS filter is
>   applied, the same filter commonly used
>   for properly displaying PNGs with
>   alpha transparency. For example,
>   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
>   (src='/path/to/image.jpg',
>   sizingMethod='scale');. While there is
>   no transparency to apply here, the
>   resizing method applied gives a
>   higher-quality result.

I cant make it work yet, actually I haven't ever used filters. Maybe anyone can give me working code?

Comment: Relying on the browser to scale images will never give you consistent results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unstoppable Robot Ninja](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images/) has an article with more information and some code to make it work on IE6 and IE7.

The problem is not IE specific, but platform specific. Firefox, Safari etc. all use their own rendering engine that scales much smoother than native Windows scaling does.

I'd advise to add the CSS declarations or JavaScript code in [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), so non IE browsers don't have to download the extra code or issue another request. This also keeps your CSS clean and valid.

Answer (score 5):

Joel Spolsky posted a solution to this on this blog recently:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/12/22.html

Add to following to the CSS:

```
img { -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }
```

The best solution is to use images that do not need to be scaled by the browser, but the CSS Joel suggests to a great improvement.

Comment: hm.. I tried and it doesn't work :( can anyone give me working example?

Comment: I don't have an IE6 handy to try it with, but I saw Joel's article at the time he published it, tested it and found it worked for me.

Comment: @RichieHindle: I've just real original article (Joel gave a reference) and it was sad that I should use some filters for ie6 because without filters it works in ie7+)

Comment: Definitely use it as a IE hack by adding some condicional :)